#  search query in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with one field as name.The values in this fields are

- `kiran-(ki-ran).txt,
  arun-(ar-un-ki-ran).txt,
  aby-(ki-ran-aby).txt`

How i can search the values excatly matching `ki-ran(inside bracket)` from this values so i can get only `kiran-(ki-ran).txt`
i have used `LIKE ('%ki-ran%')` But it is showing all the values.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LIKE clause should look like `LIKE '%(ki-ran)%'`.